# Network Policy Server + RADIUS not listening on any ports for Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, radius, netstat, windows-server-2019

I must be missing something basic - is there some "master" switch for enabling Network Policy Server?  It's not listening on any of the RADIUS ports.  Detail:

Trying to setup Windows Server 2019 as a RADIUS server.  However, after configuring everything, "netstat -b" shows that **the machine is not listening on any of the expected RADIUS ports (1812, 1645, 1813, 1646)**.

1. Installed the "Network Policy and Access Services" role
2. Followed the "Configure VPN or Dial-up" wizard
   [image: RADIUS wizard]
3. Confirmed RADIUS configuration: [image: RADIUS config]
4. Confirmed "Network Policy Server" ports: [image: NPS ports]
5. Confirmed the "Network Policy Server" service is running.

Result: "netstat -b" shows that the machine is not listening on any of the expected RADIUS ports (1812, 1645, 1813, 1646).

Have tried with no luck:

1. Rebooting
2. Restarting the "Network Policy Server" service

Comment: I had a similar issue. After some time, I found the ports in the normal (non-listen) part of the output in netstat. Turned out that the firewall did not work correctly: The rules for NPS were there, but did still not let packets through (checked in the firewall-logs). I added an additional rule for the ports and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

netstat -b does not return any information for NPS port 1812 but netstat -na | findstr 1812 does on Windows 2019 Server.

There is a bug in NPS on Windows Server 2019 where it fails to register properly with Windows Firewall. See https://blog.topqore.com/radius-authentication-using-nps-on-server-2019-bug/ for detailed information. The fix listed in the article worked successfully for me.

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Policy Server" | where DisplayName -like "*RADIUS*" | Set-NetFirewallRule -Service Any
```

This changes the Service in the NPS rules in the Windows Firewall from IAS to Any.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf047df5-ed4a-46b9-9564-c9db5a9bc8dc/windows-server-2019-default-nps-firewall-rules-port-1812-udp-not-working?forum=ws2019

Social.Technet also lists a fix using "sc sidtype IAS unrestricted" but I have not tested this.

The firewall issue was the underlying problem for me. Using the wrong netstat command send me on a wild goose chase for a little while:)